# Read file from deep nested directories in Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

This is my first attempt to work with Google Drive from Java. I need to read a file with a path like `/foo/bar/xpto/some.txt`. Looking to the library, it seems that I need to do multiple calls to Google Drive in order to get some fileID and then read the file.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Split the path in an array like `["foo","bar","xpto","some.txt"]` and then do a request of a level at a time. Looks to to be the only way, but it looks ridiculous to do 4 requests just for this.

Comment: I see, can you show how you are implementing this in Java? Are you using the Google Drive API?  How are you getting one file ID? If you have a code solution please attach it to your question so we can use it as a starting point to provide help.